# Inverse Eigenvalue Problem for symmetric matrcies with no unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse-problems

I am solving an IEP but the form of the problem and the constraints is such that it has not unique solution. It may have many different solutions. I would like to know is there any problem if such thing happens?

---

#### Update

I am solving the problem of producing a matrix $A$ whose off-diagonal entries are correspond to the Wheel graph by the given eigenvalues $\lambda = \{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \cdots , \lambda_n\}$ and vector $X$  such that $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A_i$ where $A_i$ is the $i$th leading principal submatrix of $A$ and $X$ is an eigenvector of $A$.

I solved this problem for Path graph with unique solution but for Wheel graph the given information doesn't produce a unique solution.

> If any entry of the $A$ is given as input, then the problem will have unique solution

But I think it is not a good idea to ask user to give one of the entries !

Comment: Look up "degeneracy".

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Math1000 I updated the question

Comment: @R_Berger I updated the question

Comment: @R_Berger I think it would be good to limit the problem. But I really have no idea what kind of limitation is good for it!